# Сохранение ul списка из dom-дерева на JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

я ещё только учусь, поэтому не кидайте камнями, пожалуйста)
Мне нужно реализовать сохранение списка товаров (добавленных в корзину), чтобы они не терялись при перезагрузке. Нашёл информацию, что надо это делать с помощью localStorage, но никак не получается реализовать. Ниже код самой корзины, заранее спасибо

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var cartWrapper = $('.cd-cart-container');
  //product id - you don't need a counter in your real project but you can use your real product id
  var productId = 0;

  if (cartWrapper.length > 0) {
    //store jQuery objects
    var cartBody = cartWrapper.find('.body')
    var cartList = cartBody.find('ul').eq(0);
    var cartTotal = cartWrapper.find('.checkout').find('span');
    var cartTrigger = cartWrapper.children('.cd-cart-trigger');
    var cartCount = cartTrigger.children('.count')
    var addToCartBtn = $('.cd-add-to-cart');
    var undo = cartWrapper.find('.undo');
    var undoTimeoutId;

    //add product to cart
    addToCartBtn.on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addToCart($(this));
    });

    //open/close cart
    cartTrigger.on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      toggleCart();
    });

    //close cart when clicking on the .cd-cart-container::before (bg layer)
    cartWrapper.on('click', function(event) {
      if ($(event.target).is($(this))) toggleCart(true);
    });

    //delete an item from the cart
    cartList.on('click', '.delete-item', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      removeProduct($(event.target).parents('.product'));
    });

    //update item quantity
    cartList.on('change', 'select', function(event) {
      quickUpdateCart();
    });

    //reinsert item deleted from the cart
    undo.on('click', 'a', function(event) {
      clearInterval(undoTimeoutId);
      event.preventDefault();
      cartList.find('.deleted').addClass('undo-deleted').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function() {
        $(this).off('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend').removeClass('deleted undo-deleted').removeAttr('style');
        quickUpdateCart();
      });
      undo.removeClass('visible');
    });
  }

  function toggleCart(bool) {
    var cartIsOpen = (typeof bool === 'undefined') ? cartWrapper.hasClass('cart-open') : bool;

    if (cartIsOpen) {
      cartWrapper.removeClass('cart-open');
      //reset undo
      clearInterval(undoTimeoutId);
      undo.removeClass('visible');
      cartList.find('.deleted').remove();

      setTimeout(function() {
        cartBody.scrollTop(0);
        //check if cart empty to hide it
        if (Number(cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text()) == 0) cartWrapper.addClass('empty');
      }, 500);
    } else {
      cartWrapper.addClass('cart-open');
    }
  }

  function addToCart(trigger) {
    var cartIsEmpty = cartWrapper.hasClass('empty');
    //update cart product list
    addProduct();
    //update number of items 
    updateCartCount(cartIsEmpty);
    //update total price
    updateCartTotal(trigger.data('price'), true);
    //show cart
    cartWrapper.removeClass('empty');
  }

  function addProduct() {
    //this is just a product placeholder
    //you should insert an item with the selected product info
    //replace productId, productName, price and url with your real product info
    productId = productId + 1;
    var productAdded = $('<li class="product"><div class="product-image"><a href="#0"><img src="img/product-preview.png" alt="placeholder"></a></div><div class="product-details"><h3><a href="#0">Product Name</a></h3><span class="price">$25.99</span><div class="actions"><a href="#0" class="delete-item">Delete</a><div class="quantity"><label for="cd-product-' + productId + '">Qty</label><span class="select"><select id="cd-product-' + productId + '" name="quantity"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option></select></span></div></div></div></li>');
    cartList.prepend(productAdded);
  }

  function removeProduct(product) {
    clearInterval(undoTimeoutId);
    cartList.find('.deleted').remove();

    var topPosition = product.offset().top - cartBody.children('ul').offset().top,
      productQuantity = Number(product.find('.quantity').find('select').val()),
      productTotPrice = Number(product.find('.price').text().replace('$', '')) * productQuantity;

    product.css('top', topPosition + 'px').addClass('deleted');

    //update items count + total price
    updateCartTotal(productTotPrice, false);
    updateCartCount(true, -productQuantity);
    undo.addClass('visible');

    //wait 8sec before completely remove the item
    undoTimeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      undo.removeClass('visible');
      cartList.find('.deleted').remove();
    }, 8000);
  }

  function quickUpdateCart() {
    var quantity = 0;
    var price = 0;

    cartList.children('li:not(.deleted)').each(function() {
      var singleQuantity = Number($(this).find('select').val());
      quantity = quantity + singleQuantity;
      price = price + singleQuantity * Number($(this).find('.price').text().replace('$', ''));
    });

    cartTotal.text(price.toFixed(2));
    cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text(quantity);
    cartCount.find('li').eq(1).text(quantity + 1);
  }

  function updateCartCount(emptyCart, quantity) {
    if (typeof quantity === 'undefined') {
      var actual = Number(cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text()) + 1;
      var next = actual + 1;

      if (emptyCart) {
        cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text(actual);
        cartCount.find('li').eq(1).text(next);
      } else {
        cartCount.addClass('update-count');

        setTimeout(function() {
          cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text(actual);
        }, 150);

        setTimeout(function() {
          cartCount.removeClass('update-count');
        }, 200);

        setTimeout(function() {
          cartCount.find('li').eq(1).text(next);
        }, 230);
      }
    } else {
      var actual = Number(cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text()) + quantity;
      var next = actual + 1;

      cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text(actual);
      cartCount.find('li').eq(1).text(next);
    }
  }

  function updateCartTotal(price, bool) {
    bool ? cartTotal.text((Number(cartTotal.text()) + Number(price)).toFixed(2)) : cartTotal.text((Number(cartTotal.text()) - Number(price)).toFixed(2));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <h1>Add to Cart Interaction</h1>
  <a href="#0" class="cd-add-to-cart" data-price="25.99">Add To Cart</a>
</main>


<div class="cd-cart-container empty">
  <a href="#0" class="cd-cart-trigger">
 
    Cart

    <ul class="count"> <!-- cart items count -->
      <li>0</li>
      <li>0</li>
    </ul> <!-- .count -->
  </a>

  <div class="cd-cart">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <h2>Cart</h2>
        <span class="undo">Item removed. <a href="#0">Undo</a></span>
      </header>

      <div class="body">
        <ul>
          <!-- products added to the cart will be inserted here using JavaScript -->
        </ul>
      </div>

      <footer>
        <a href="#0" class="checkout btn"><em>Checkout - $<span>0</span></em></a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .cd-cart -->
</div>
<!-- cd-cart-container -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простите, не обнаружил в вашем коде моделей данных, но опишу пример с ними.

Представьте, что у вас есть модель данных некого продукта и визуализируется она у вас с помощью элемента `li` списка `ul`.

Чтобы сохранить\загрузить данные из хранилища `localStorage` воспользуйтесь JSON -

```js
function saveData(key, data) {
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    localStorage.setItem(key, jsonData);
}

function loadStorageData(key) {
    var jsonData = localStorage.getItem(key, jsonData); // getItem может вернуть undefined
    return JSON.parse(jsonData);
}
```

В вашем случае можно упростить использование параметра `key`, например.